# Display one color (of a configurable product) on its own

Tags: magento-1.8, configurable-product

I have the following situation:

I have many configurable products that are all configured by color and size.
All simple products associated to these configurables are not individually visible.
The configurable products are linked to a category.

Now i want to display one of the colors in a second category as well.

I came up with the idea of creating a new configurable product for each color I want to show on its own and only associate the simple products with the color I want to show.

Is this the correct way to achieve this? Or is there a way to achieve this without having to create extra configurable product?

Answer (score 1):

You can can assign that specific color's simple product and it's configurable product to that second category and other product is not assigned to this category.